# QML2_IMPORT_PATH not set despite call in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: qt, module, cmake, qml

I'm trying to import my own module in my `CMake`-based `Qt` project.

**qmldir.txt**

```
module MyModule
MyModuleLabel 1.0 MyModuleLabel.qml
```

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path), I need to set the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` variable.

```
SET(QML2_IMPORT_PATH "/graphics")
```

Alternatively, I can also use `QQmlEngine::addImportPath()`.

I tried both ways and it doesn't work. `QQmlEngine::importPathList()` doesn't display my path hence the compiler saying:

`module "MyModule" is not installed`

What am I missing?

Comment: CMake configures the build and environment variables in cmake will only have effect at *build time*, while the QML2_IMPORT_PATH is relevant only at *run time*. The build system is the wrong place for this. (You could install the modules to together with the executable and use addImportPath() together with QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()).

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood your last sentence. I tried the following: `engine.addImportPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/graphics");` and moved my `graphics` folder in the binary directory. Module is still not found.
Note that the QML files of the `graphics` folder are not linked in the `.qrc` file. Those graphics elements should be seen as independant from the project.

Comment: The file should be name `qmldir` without any extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Frank Osterfeld said, the `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable is only relevant at runtime, it's not where I'd set my import path.

The way to do it at is using `QQmlEngine::addImportPath()`
If your import path is `/foo/bar/modules/` and you try to `import MyModule 1.0`, the QML engine will try to look for a file named `qmldir` (with no extension) in `/foo/bar/modules/MyModule/`.
So the complet path of your file should be `/foo/bar/modules/MyModule/qmldir`

Comment: I had forgotten to create a folder with the same name as my module. In that case, it gives `/path/to/project/graphics/MyModule/` with the `QML` and `qmldir` files within it.